# iPhone SDK 4.0 Animation Blocks - Move Scale UIImage

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios4

`myImageView`:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
  animations:^{

  } 
  completion:^(BOOL finished) {

  }
];
```

How can I animate `myImageView` (position/scale) using animation blocks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use CGAffineTransformations, like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
  animations:^{
      CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
      CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(10.0, 10.0);

      self.myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(scale, translate);

  } 
  completion:^(BOOL finished) {

  }
];
```

Here I make transforms for `scale` and `transform`, and then use `CGAffineTransformConcat` to combine them.

Docs are [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html)

HTH